# Proper way to find max value and bring it back inside loop in Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

As you can see default method of reassigning maximum is limited by max value from current iteration (see left text-window)

Writing max value outside the loop and bringing it back through *Set/Get Attribute* (see right text-window) is working but it's bulky when needed more Subprograms to copy.

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? I would say just use the *Float List Math* node to get the max then do what you want with it.

Comment: Your suggestion is technically correct for this example. Real thing I am parsing some 2d vectors from text data, calculating distances and other stuff inside loop, then need max distance to go further...

Comment: My advice, don't complicate things, create your node tree and leave optimizations after your are done. Moreover, if the execution time is reasonable, don't waste your time on further optimizations, you are better off doing something else. Just to make sure, what is your question currently?